# Find all values of $\log{(-1-i)}$

Tags: complex-analysis

This is what I have so far...

$$\Large{\log{(-1-i)}=\log{(\sqrt{2}e^{\frac{i5\pi}{4} + 2k\pi})} = \frac{1}{2}\log2+\frac{i5\pi}{4}+2k\pi}$$

Thank you in advance for any helps.

~Rabbit

Comment: The 2kpi term is also subject to the $i$ upfront, so put the $i$ outside the bracket, not inside

Comment: @randomUser It is the argument plus its multiples entirely multiplied by $i$ (unless you intentionally did not change that only to edit Rabbit's wording)

Comment: @imranfat Is the issue with the question as originally posed, or specifically with an error I made when converting to $\LaTeX$?

Comment: @Radomuser Joe (below) addressed my concern

Comment: It was my mistake.  The i should be outside, as in i(5pi/4 + 2kpi), correct?

Answer (score 2):

Almost done! You only missed a $i$ in the exponent of $e$.

Since
\begin{align*}
-1-i=&\sqrt2e^{i\frac54\pi}\\
=&\sqrt2e^{i\frac54\pi+2k\pi i}\\
=&\sqrt2e^{i\pi\left(\frac54+2k\right)},\;\;k\in\mathbb Z
\end{align*}
You get

\begin{align*}
\log(-1-i)=&\log\left(\sqrt2e^{i\pi\left(\frac54+2k\right)}\right)\\
\stackrel{}{=}&\log\left|\sqrt2e^{i\pi\left(\frac54+2k\right)}\right|+i\arg\left(\sqrt2e^{i\pi\left(\frac54+2k\right)}\right)\\
=&\log\sqrt2+i\pi\left(\frac54+2k\right),\;\;k\in\mathbb Z.
\end{align*}

Comment: ~ Thank you!  Makes a lot more sense!

Comment: You're welcome! :)